# File I/O has caused a "[Conflict]"

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, corruption

I wrote a small program that is supposed to run continuously analyzing some data. I usually just let it run in the background on my computer. A couple of times now, I have come back to my computer to notice that the program had stopped running. Eventually, I noticed that in the same directory as the .csv file I use to store data in ("data.csv"), there was a similarly named file "data[Conflict].csv", which I suspect probably has something to do with the program mysteriously crashing.

I tried Googling "python '[conflict]'" in addition to several other similar phrases, but have been unable to find anything regarding this. Nowhere in my code did I attempt to read or write to a file with this name, so I know that this functionality must be somewhere part of Python's standard libraries. Unfortunately, in order to debug the error, I sort of need to know what might produce this sort of output. (Alternatively, I could stare at the program for hours on end waiting for the crash to see if something revealing occurs, but I have better things to do with my time.)  Any idea what might be causing this behavior?

For what it's worth, without going into the details of the data I'm actually analyzing, this is basically what I do with "data.csv":

- When the program starts, open the data into a buffer, verify its integrity (the entries in the .csv are all time-stamped, so I simply check to see if the entries are all chronological)
- I pull new data from the server, write it to the end of the buffer, and do some analysis.
- Roughly every 5 minutes or so, I verify the integrity of the buffer, write the new data to the end of my locally-stored data file, re-verify integrity of the data, pull new data from the server, and repeat.

I am using 64-bit Python 3.3.1 for Windows.

Comment: I've never heard of python automatically renaming files like that. I could be wrong, however. Perhaps it has to do with some other program installed on your computer? Maybe one that is responsible for synchronization of some sort. I know dropbox renames files if there are two conflicting versions.

Comment: For what it's worth, it's not re-naming per se; it's making a copy of the file with that slightly different name, so that I have two files:  "data.csv" and "data[Conflict].csv".  It is always the case that the former is slightly larger than the latter, as if the program had kept on running and updating that file for at least a little while.  Not sure what that means.

Comment: What modules are you using in your program?

Comment: `import hmac, base64, hashlib, time, urllib, csv, json, math` and `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` are the only `import` commands (except for a single `import time` that is in my 'launcher' file).